# How to create cookies in AEM in Java in ViewHelper?

Tags: java, jsp, aem, aem-6

I have a requirement that I have to create a cookie on server side when page loads. In our AEM project I have a LocatorViewESBOfficeHelper.java file which is mapped to the JSP of the component (Say locateOffice). When page loads first time onGetData method of LocatorViewESBOfficeHelper.java is called.

In this method I want to create cookie using following code but I am unable to create it. When I use same create cookie code in a servlet and call it through ajax call, it successfully create cookie.

[image]

One possible reason could be when page is fully loaded, the response object could not have cookies. But I am unable to understand how to manage it.

Comment: jsp in AEM 6? I mean.. why?

Comment: Please do not try to declare your questions as "not a duplicate". You may have missed a good duplicate, and it is good to be open to receiving one.

Answer (score 1):

You might have several problems.

**Edit-Mode**

You will not see session cookies in the editor, because your page is inside an iframe. Just do "View as published" (*?wcmmode=disabled*) to get your page directly in the browser window.

**Wrong response object**

The mapping LocatorViewESBOfficeHelper.java to the component sounds like someone tried to do some magic. Maybe your service doesn't get the real response object, but more a response wrapper. And the output of your service is somehow validated and written to the real response. In such cases, the http headers are often ignored.

Just create your own real AEM component, were the content is written by a SlingSafeMethodsServlet (registered via the resource type). If this works, you know where to go.

The following servlet does work good for me:

```
@Component(
    service = Servlet.class,
    property = {
        SLING_SERVLET_RESOURCE_TYPES + "=/apps/myproject/components/cookie-test",
        SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=GET",
        SLING_SERVLET_EXTENSIONS + "=html"
})
public class CookieTestServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(@Nonnull SlingHttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h2>Cookie Test</h2>");
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("alex", "this-is-a-test-" + (System.currentTimeMillis() % 10000));
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

**Response buffer already flushed**

The *HttpServletResponse* is more like a buffered *Writer* or *OutputStream*. You can only add http headers (or cookies) as long as the response output buffer was not flushed yet.

To verify this, either use the test component on a smaller page or simply increase in the OSGi configs the buffer to something real high (e.g. 1MB - but on your local instance only). Therefore go to the web console / OSGi / Configuration / 
**Apache Felix Jetty Based Http Service** / **Response buffer size**

(http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/org.apache.felix.http)

I don't recommend to change it in production. So you should find another way to be early in the content generation. As most extreme workaround you could use a Sling request filter.

**Opt-Out-Filter**

If your project uses the **Adobe Granite Opt-Out Service**, then you might have to whitelist your cookie in the OSGi configuration. By default this service should not do anything.

**Try Other Alternatives**

As alternative I would propose:

- Use a Sling Filter
- Create the Cookie front-end with JavaScript

I hope one of my ideas might point you in the right direction.

Alex